# Using react_component() to add react components in haml files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, haml, react-rails

While working with the `react-rails` library, we can use the [react_component()](https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails#7-render-it-in-a-rails-view) function in an `.erb` file to add a react component.

How can we use the same function in a `.haml` file? Or do we have another way of adding a react component in a haml file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If webpacker is setup in your RoR project, then you can simply use the `react_component` function from `react-rails` in the same way we would add ruby code to the haml file.

Ex:

```html
%li
  = react_component("ReactComponent")
```

This should work correctly. Webpacker will try to locate the React component in `app/javascript/components` by default.